# Arrays to integers in matlab. how do you do it

Tags: matlab

```
x=[.4 1 1.4 1.9 2.4]
y=[.3 .6 .9 1.2 1.5]
for (i=1:10)
    for (j=1:10)
        T(x,y)=x.^2+.6.*x.*y.^3-2.*y.^4
    end
end
surf(T')
```

I have this and I get the error "Subscript indices must either be real
positive integers or logicals." I am told its because my x and y are arrays not integers but how do I make them integers?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the loop?

Comment: @user3440208 if one of the answers helped you mark it as "accepted" (the check on the left) - so the system knows the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid([.4 1 1.4 1.9 2.4], [.3 .6 .9 1.2 1.5]);
T = X.^2+.6.*X.*Y.^3-2.*Y.^4;
surf(T');
```

Comment: Almost, assuming @user3440208 wants the 1st index to correspond to x (hence the transpose in `surf(T')`), you'd need `[Y, X] = meshgrid([.3 .6 .9 1.2 1.5],[.4 1 1.4 1.9 2.4]);`. Meshgrid doesn't do indices the way you might expect.

Comment: I didn't realized that in the question he was doing `T(x,y)=..` so I didn't understand why he had put the transpose of T at the end.. now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your attempts.

given:

```
x = [.4 1 1.4 1.9 2.4]
y = [.3 .6 .9 1.2 1.5]
```

1) You are iterating over more elements than you actually have: `for (i=1:10)` should rather be `for (i=1:5)` - but you shouldn't use `i` and `j` as iteration variables. So use:

```
for ii = 1:numel(x)          %// numel(x) = number of elements of x = 5
```

2) For indexing of your variable `T` you need to use your iteration variables and not `x` and `y` itself.

**The loop could then look like that:**

```
for ii = 1:numel(x)          
    for jj = 1:numel(y)      
        T(ii,jj)= x(ii)^2 + .6*x(ii)*y(jj)^3 - 2*y(jj)^4;
    end
end
surf(T)
```

The shorter versions you can find in the [answer of Gastón](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22522093/2605073)

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
T = X.^2 + .6.*X.*Y.^3 - 2.*Y.^4;
surf(T');
```

You might wonder why you need to transpose `T` - thats because `meshgrid` swaps the inputs.
Alternatively use `ndgrid`:

```
[X, Y] = ndgrid(x, y);
T = X.^2+.6.*X.*Y.^3-2.*Y.^4;
surf(T);
```

All three returning:

[image]

which makes not too much sense as your `x-axis` and `y-axis` is totally unrelated to your actually values. Therefore your surface is misshaped. Use the outputs `X` and `Y` of `meshgrid` as additional inputs for `surf`:

```
surf(X,Y,T');
```

returing the figure I assume you want:

[image]

Comment: thanks for correcting the mistakes!, I totally forgot about to pass the values of X and Y to `surf`. Maybe in a real application in which the axis have some semantic I would have noticed..